# Use one array in multiple functions in powershell

Tags: powershell

I would like to read the content of a text file and add it to an array. I'm using a `Get-Content` to do this.

I would like to know how I can use this array in two or more functions.

The array is quite large 150 MB, I think creating the same array for each function is not efficient.

```
function msgList1 ($file){
   $string = "-----------------------------------------------------------------------"
   $record = ""
   $myLine = ""
   $count = 0
   $idxNumber = 0
   $LineNumber = 0
   $count = 0
   $date = @()
   $records = @()


   foreach($line in $file){

        if($line.contains("string of some kind")){
           $myFields = $line.Split(' ')
           [int]$count = $myFields[9] -replace "count="

           While($record -ne $string){
              if($LineNumber -lt 0){break}
              if($count -gt 500){break}
              $LineNumber--
              $record = $file[$LineNumber]
              $count++
           }
           if($count -lt 500 -and $LineNumber -gt 0){
                 $myLine = $file[$LineNumber+1]

                 #Get date and time
                 $dt = $myLine.Split(' ')
                 $date = $dt[1]
                 $time = $dt[2]

                 $newString = $date, $V5time, [string]$count -join " "
                 $records += $newString
                 $record = ""
                 $count = 0
           }
        }
        if($count -ge 500 -or $LineNumber -lt 0){
                  $newString = [string]$count
                  $records += $newString
                  $count = 0
        }

        $LineNumber++
        $idxNumber++

        $LineNumber = $idxNumber
   }

   $records | Out-File "C:\Files\Log Report\Log1Report.txt" -Encoding ascii –Force
}


function msgList2 ($file){
   $string = "-----------------------------------------------------------------------"
   $record = ""
   $myLine = ""
   $count = 0
   $idxNumber = 0
   $LineNumber = 0
   $count = 0
   $date = @()
   $records = @()


   foreach($line in $file){

        if($line.contains("string of some kind")){
           $myFields = $line.Split(' ')
           [int]$count = $myFields[9] -replace "number="

           While($record -ne $string){
              if($LineNumber -lt 0){break}
              if($count -gt 500){break}
              $LineNumber--
              $record = $file[$LineNumber]
              $count++
           }
           if($count -lt 500 -and $LineNumber -gt 0){
                 $myLine = $file[$LineNumber+1]

                 #Get date and time
                 $dt = $myLine.Split(' ')
                 $date = $dt[1]
                 $time = $dt[2]

                 $newString = $date, $V5time, [string]$count -join " "
                 $records += $newString
                 $record = ""
                 $count = 0
           }
        }
        if($count -ge 500 -or $LineNumber -lt 0){
                  $newString = [string]$count
                  $records += $newString
                  $count = 0
        }

        $LineNumber++
        $idxNumber++

        $LineNumber = $idxNumber
   }

   $records | Out-File "C:\Files\Log Report\Log2Report.txt" -Encoding ascii –Force
}

msgList1 -file (Get-Content -Path "C:\Files\Log.txt")
msgList2 -file (Get-Content -Path "C:\Files\Log.txt")
```

Comment: So just Get-Content once and assign that to a variable then pass the variable to each function in turn

Comment: If you do `$VariableName = @(Get-Content -Path $Path)`, it will store the file into the variable as an array of strings, FYI.  The `@()` syntax forces it to return as a literal array.

Answer (score 0):

You can also make it an environment variable with:

```
$env:YourArrayVariable = Get-Content -Path "\\Path\to\your\file"
```

And then just use it instead of that $file

Comment: The variable will still be limited to that session, so adding it to the `env:` drive doesn't really do anything

Comment: True, but since I don't know if the first answer was "run that on the shell session" or "add that to the script where the functions are", I thought of making it part of the env: drive and then use it on any "called" functions on the same session. I should have given more details. Thanks.

Comment: The benefit I see to creating an environment variable is if you're calling cmd and you need a variable transmitted, like: `$env:A='mystring';cmd /c ECHO %A%` or if you know an application you're calling relies on environment variables and you can customize that session.